# jQuery-ui dialog don't show on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

My jQuery-ui dialog don't show when clicking on a submit button

html :

```
<input id="pdfsub" type="button" name="pdfsub" value="PDF">
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#PDFdialog").dialog({
        width: 500, autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false,
        modal: false,
        title: "pdf",
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Annuler",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }]
    });

    $("#pdfsub").click(function(){
        $("#PDFdialog").dialog("open");
        alert("btn");
    });
});
```

it show me my alert box but not the dialog , did I make a mistake somewhere ?
also my jQuery and jQuery-ui libs are working (have the same in my "connexion" page with same dialog and it's working)

> EDIT :

There are my libs

```
<script src="/jquery-ui-1.12.1/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is your input button inside a <form>

Comment: Yes  it is  want me to edit ?

Comment: Your code should work : http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/ymssceqv/193/

Comment: Your code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ymssceqv/194/ May be you have missed the library in your code.

Comment: in your shared HTML there is no `#PDFdialog`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki your code doesn't show the text i put in "text" options of the dialog .

Comment: @MihaiT is that mandatory to have a div with same ID as my dialog?  i don't have it on my other page and it's working fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/5am33nuu/1/ the button text is "Annuler" as you describe in the code what you want else ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki well i just forgot that a div was needed to make the dialog work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying dialog function to a div that does not exist in your HTML structure and you don't create it in javascript/jquery either.

So you must have an element with that id inside your html so you can call that dialog on it

As you can see in the example on jQueryUI site 
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#PDFdialog").dialog({
        width: 500, autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false,
        modal: false,
        title: "pdf",
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Annuler",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }]
    });

    $("#pdfsub").click(function(){
        $("#PDFdialog").dialog("open");

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="pdfsub" type="button" name="pdfsub" value="PDF">
<div id="PDFdialog">
</div>
```